# Compare eigenvalues of comparable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, bilinear-form

Consider two symmetric matrices $A,B$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and assume that $A\geq B$ as bilinear forms, i.e. $A(x,x)\geq B(x,x)$ for any vector $x$. Let $(\lambda_i)$ and $(\mu_i)$ be the ordered (possibly repeated with multiplicity) eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$, respectively. Is it true that $\lambda_i\geq\mu_i$ for every $i=1,...,n$?
The result is obviously true when I can diagonalize the matrices simultaneously, but I am not sure what I can say in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is true in general by the Courant-Fischer min-max theorem.

Comment: Can you sketch a proof?

Comment: By the theorem, 
$$ \lambda_i = \min \max \frac{\langle Ax,x \rangle}{||x||^2}$$ 
with appropriate minimum and maximum, and same for $\mu_i$ with respect to $B$. The relation $\langle Ax,x\rangle \geq \langle Bx,x\rangle$ implies the statement.